# Cannot use the mouse while trying to Edit low quality posts (through reviews)

Tags: bug, review-queues

I faced this many times now and I am not sure whether I am the only one. While reviewing posts (today Low Quality flagged, I don't remember about the others), I clicked on Edit to improve the formatting of one of them.

On the editing screen, unfortunately I cannot use the mouse at all (for setting the cursor or for clicking the save button or else). I had to completely do it using the keyboard (arrows and tabs).

I am running Google Chrome (auto-updated) on top of a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Happens in IE too.

Comment: Firefox too!  I have noticed it for several weeks.  I have also noticed it on different networks.  It appears to be a bug

Comment: Chrome on Windows 8 as well.

Comment: In fact, it's most of the page; not just textboxes. There isn't an element blocking, so it might be an event preventing default or something. I don't have time to investigate right now but I will later.